# How to group the elements in an array based on status property in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, lodash

I have am array of object i.e. JSON like this in my react state and before rendering it I want it to sort based on status property example-
**Actual Value**

```
{
"list": [
{
   "id": "aac",
   "name": "James",
   "status": "active"
},
{
   "id": "gds",
   "name": "Alice",
   "status": "left"
},
{
   "id": "cvs",
   "name": "Kristy",
   "status": "active"
},
{
   "id": "cgt",
   "name": "Samaira",
   "status": "left"
},
]
}
```

**Expecting Value** after sorting based on status element

```
{
"list": [
{
   "id": "aac",
   "name": "James",
   "status": "active"
},
{
   "id": "cvs",
   "name": "Kristy",
   "status": "active"
},

{
   "id": "gds",
   "name": "Alice",
   "status": "left"
},

{
   "id": "cgt",
   "name": "Samaira",
   "status": "left"
},
]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: If you need to **sort** an **array** in **javascript** I suggest you google "sort array javascript" to read the documentation on Array.sort at MDN which is the first result : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will sort alphabetically by status

```js
arrayName.sort((objA, objB) => objA.status > objB.status ? 1 : -1)
```

Comment: Thank You! It worked. Didn't knew that I can use sort method on strings too. But I learnt :-p